# utils.ts:874 Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, element

utils.ts:874

How do I fix this I haven't a clue.

> Matched leaf route at location "/action" does not have an element.
> This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default
> resulting in an "empty" page.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import CardGroup from 'react-bootstrap/CardGroup';
import Logo from './logo.png';

class Action extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <font color="white"><h1>Action Based Shows</h1></font>
        {/*Hard coded shows in cards */}
        <CardGroup>
          <Card bg="dark" text="white">
            <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5675620/"><Card.Img src="http://ayanahaviv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/34-The-Punisher.jpg" /></a>
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>The Punisher</Card.Title>
              2017-2019
              <Card.Text>
                A rocky start can't keep The Punisher from pushing the boundaries of Marvel's TV universe with a fresh take on the comics-derived action thriller.
              </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Action;
```

Comment: Somewhere you are rendering a `Route` component with `path="/action"` and not passing any `element` prop. You should probably include ***that*** code for your [mcve]. Can you [edit] the post to include the relevant code causing the issue(s)?

Comment: is this the code your looking for or do you need more? '            <Route path="/action" Component={action} />
'